# My symmetric difference function is returning none and I can't understand why

Tags: python-3.x, function, return-value

Trying to solve freecodecamp's symmetric difference challenge (https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/coding-interview-prep/algorithms/find-the-symmetric-difference), I wrote the following function:

```
def symdiff(*args):
    dump = [x for x in args[0] if x in args[1]]
    result = [x for x in args[0] + args[1] if x not in dump]    
    if len(args) == 2:
        return result
    else:
        symdiff(result, *args[2:])
var = symdiff([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 0], [7, 2, 6])
print(var)
```

The value of var turns out to be None. Why is that? I expected it to be [7, 2, 6, 1, 0]. I entered a print(result) just before return result and it printed the correct answer.

Comment: Your ```else``` needs to return symdiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `else` block, you need to return `symdiff`.

```
def symdiff(*args):
    dump = [x for x in args[0] if x in args[1]]
    result = [x for x in args[0] + args[1] if x not in dump]    
    if len(args) == 2:
        return result
    else:
        return symdiff(result, *args[2:])
var = symdiff([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 0], [7, 2, 6])
print(var)
```

The above code should work.